# How to create go back button after reload Symfony/twig

Tags: symfony, button, twig, symfony4, symfony-forms

I use Symfony 4.4. I have a go back button in my Twig template.

```
{% if previousPageboolean == false %}
        <a class="d-block text-decoration-none cursor px-4 pt-3" href="{{app.request.headers.get('referer')}}"><img src="{{ asset('build/images/back.svg')}}" class="height-19"></a>
{%else%}
        <a class="d-block text-decoration-none cursor px-4 pt-3" href="{{referer}}"><img src="{{ asset('build/images/back.svg')}}" class="height-19"></a>
{% endif %}
```

But I have a problem. It works but in this template I have 2 forms. When I click the submit button of these buttons, flash messeges apper and reload the page. So when page reload the route of the go back button change and it is the own page.

Controller

```
 /**
 * @Route("/receta/{title}", name="recipe_show", methods={"GET"})
 * @Route("/receta/{title}", name="recipe_show")
 */
public function show(Recipe $recipe,RecipeRepository $recipeRepository,ScoreRepository $scoreRepository,CommentRepository $commentRepository, Request $request): Response
{ 
    $comment = new Comment();
    $score = new Score();

    $comment_form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
    $comment_form->handleRequest($request);
    
    $score_form = $this->createForm(ScoreType::class, $score);
    $score_form->handleRequest($request);

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $referrer="";
    $previousPageboolean =false;

    if ($score_form->isSubmitted() && $score_form->isValid()) {  
        $previousPageboolean =true;
        $referrer = $request->get('referrer');

        $score_value = $score_form->get("score")->getData();

        $isScore = $scoreRepository->findBy(array('user' => $user , 'recipe' => $recipe->getId()));
        
        if($isScore == [] ){
            $score->setScore($score_value); 
            $score->setRecipe($recipe); 
            $score->setUser($user);
            $entityManager->persist($score); 
            $entityManager->flush();  

            $this->addFlash('success', '¡Puntuación registrada con exito!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute($request->getUri(), [
                'referrer' => $this->generateUrl($request->attributes->get('_route'),
                   array_merge(
                       $this->request->atrributes->get('_route_params'),
                       $this->request->query->all
                   ), 
                ),
            ]);  
        }else{
            $this->addFlash('danger', 'Ya existe una puntuación registrada para esta receta con este usuario.');
            return $this->redirect($request->getUri()); 
        }              
    }   

    if ($comment_form->isSubmitted() && $comment_form->isValid()) {
        $parentid = $comment_form->get("parent")->getData();

        if($parentid != null){
            $parent = $entityManager->getRepository(Comment::class)->find($parentid);
        }

        $comment->setVisible(1);
        $comment->setParent($parent ?? null);
        $comment->setUser($user);
        $comment->setRecipe($recipe);
        $comment->setCreatedAt(new DateTime());        
        $entityManager->persist($comment);
        $entityManager->flush();  

        $this->addFlash('success', '¡Comentario registrado con exito!');
        return $this->redirect($request->getUri());     
    }

    $comments = $commentRepository->findCommentsByRecipe($recipe);

    return $this->render('recipe/show/show.html.twig', [
        'recipe' => $recipe,
        'score_form' => $score_form->createView(),
        'comment_form' => $comment_form->createView(),
        'comments' => $comments,
        'referrer' => $referrer,
        'previousPageboolean' => $previousPageboolean
    ]);
}
```

It isn't a good idea to put the name of the route in the back button because the route needs the category parameter and a recipe can have more than one categories.

The recipe table haven't a category property because I have a recipes_categories table which have a M:M relationship between recipe table and category table.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I can think of is passing the refferer as a query parameter, and including it in the twig file.

In case you redirect to the current controller from twig:

```
<a href="{{path('some_path', {..., 'referrer': path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge(app.request.query.all)))})}}">Link to the current controller</a>
```

In case you redirect using RedirectResponse:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('some_path', [
    ...,
    'referrer' => $this->generateUrl($request->attributes->get('_route'),
       array_merge(
           $request->atrributes->get('_route_params'),
           $request->query->all
       ), 
    ),
]);
```

Controller:

```
public function show(Request $request, ...)
{
...
$referrer = $request->get('referrer');
...

return $this->render('recipe/show/show.html.twig', [
    ...,
    'referrer' => $referrer,
]);
```

twig:

```
<a class="d-block text-decoration-none cursor px-4 pt-3" href="{{referrer}}"><img src="{{ asset('build/images/back.svg')}}" class="height-19"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't undenstand the solution. I'm new in Symfony. Are there any other solution more easier?

Comment: The one I suggested is quite easy! I have just listed two examples depenging on the situation.

I have edited my answer to match your exact case. Maybe now it will be easier? (I still don't know if you redirect to the current Controller using twig or another controller)

Comment: Sometimes the go-back url could also be part of the form, as a hidden field. But this requires a bit more work, because you need to alter Form's etc.  The trick with the urls's is easier.

Comment: I reload from the own controller to the same URL with return $this->redirect($request->getUri()); like the controller shows. But I doesn't undenstand how the example works in my controller because if I reload the url the previous page change

Comment: I have edit the post but it doesn't works. Can you help me please? It's really important for me

Comment: You also need to add the refferer to the `return $this->redirect`

Comment: I have this error: Notice: Undefined property: App\Controller\RecipeController::$request
How can I solve it?

Comment: Add `Request $request` as first parameter of show() function
(the Request class is a symfony class from namespace HttpFoundation)

Comment: sorry I made an error in my comment, it should be `$request` instead of `$this->request`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it has something to do with your problem but I think there's a typo in your controller: array_merge(
$this->request->***atrributes***->get('_route_params'),

Comment: This feedback should be a comment, rather than an answer